# List View in QML appearing below other objects in my window

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I've created a minimum working example to show my problem. What I'm trying to do is create a working list of countries that can be filtered as the user types input. This works perfectly except for one major drawback. The list view is drawn BELOW other elements in the screen. Here is the code for a MWE to illustrate my problem.

My main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1280
    height: 720
    title: qsTr("MWE")

    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        color: "#ff0000"
        width: 440
        height: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 20
    }

    VMAutoCompleteComboBox{
        id: diagDBDefaultCountry
        width: 440
        height: 30
        vmList: {
            var list = loader.getCountryList()
            return list;
        }
        vmValues: loader.getCountryCodeList()
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 70
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        color: "#ff0000"
        width: 440
        height: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 120
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect3
        color: "#ff0000"
        width: 440
        height: 30
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 170
    }

}
```

My VMAutoCompleteComboBox.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1

Item {

    property string vmLabel : ""
    property var vmList: []
    property var vmValues: []
    property int vmMaxOptions: 10

    function filter(){

        // Creating the model list
        modelList.clear()

        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < vmList.length; i++){
           if ((vmList[i].toLowerCase().search(lineEdit.text.toLowerCase()) !== -1) || (lineEdit.text === "")){
               var data = "";
               if (i < vmValues.length) data = vmValues[i];               
               modelList.append({"vmText": vmList[i], "vmData": data, "vmIndex": count});
               count++;
               if (count == vmMaxOptions) break;
           }
        }

        // Updating the height of the patient list.
        listView.height = lineEditRect.height*(count+1);
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: lineEditRect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#ebf3fa"
        border.width: 0
        height: parent.height
    }

    ListModel {
        id: modelList
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: subLine
        width: lineEditRect.width
        height: 1;
        border.color: "#297fca"
        color: "#297fca"
        anchors.bottom: lineEditRect.bottom
    }

    TextInput {
        property bool vmFilterEnable: true
        id: lineEdit
        font.pixelSize: 13
        anchors.bottom: subLine.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
        leftPadding: 5
        width: lineEditRect.width
        onTextChanged: {
            if (!vmFilterEnable ) return;
            filter();
        }
        onCursorVisibleChanged: {
            if (cursorVisible) filter();
        }
    }

    Text{
        id: labelText
        text: vmLabel
        color:  "#297fca"
        font.pixelSize: 11
        anchors.left: lineEditRect.left
        anchors.bottom: lineEdit.top
        anchors.bottomMargin: 5
        visible: (vmLabel != "")
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        model: modelList
        anchors.top: lineEditRect.bottom
        anchors.left: lineEditRect.left
        layer.enabled: true
        clip: true
        delegate: VMAutoCompleteCBEntry {
            width: lineEditRect.width
            height: lineEditRect.height
            layer.enabled: true
            clip: true
            onClicked: {
                console.log("Clicked on text: " + text + " that has data " + data + " with index " + index);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And finally my VMAutoCompleteCBEntry

```
import QtQuick 2.6

Rectangle {

    signal clicked(string text, string data, int index);

    id: contentRect
    color: mouseDetect.containsMouse? "#cfcfcf" : "#ffffff"
    border.width: 1
    border.color: "#cfcfcf"
    z: 10

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseDetect
        hoverEnabled: true
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: contentRect.clicked(vmText,vmData,vmIndex);
    }

    Text {
        id: contentText
        text: vmText
        //color: (labelText.visible)? "#58595b" : "#cfcfcf"
        color: "#202020"
        //font.family: viewHome.robotoR.name
        font.pixelSize: 13
        verticalAlignment: TextInput.AlignVCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: contentRect.verticalCenter
        leftPadding: 5
    }

}
```

I will provide all other files in my project in order to provide a complete MWE. However the only purpose of most of the code below is just to provide a stringlist of country names and ISO country codes.

My countries.h

```
#ifndef COUNTRIES_H
#define COUNTRIES_H

#include <QStringList>

struct CountryStruct {

public:
    void fillCountryList(bool inEnglish = true) {
        if (COUNTRY_CODE.size() != 0) return;
        /// TODO: Get the country list in spanish.
        if ((inEnglish) || (!inEnglish)){
            COUNTRY_LIST <<  "Afghanistan" << "Åland Islands" << "Albania" << "Algeria" << "American Samoa" << "Andorra" << "Angola" << "Anguilla" << "Antarctica"
                          << "Antigua and Barbuda" << "Argentina" << "Armenia" << "Aruba" << "Australia" << "Austria" << "Azerbaijan" << "Bahamas" << "Bahrain"
                          << "Bangladesh" << "Barbados" << "Belarus" << "Belgium" << "Belize" << "Benin" << "Bermuda" << "Bhutan" << "Bolivia, Plurinational State of"
                          << "Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba" << "Bosnia and Herzegovina" << "Botswana" << "Bouvet Island" << "Brazil" << "British Indian Ocean Territory"
                          << "Brunei Darussalam" << "Bulgaria" << "Burkina Faso" << "Burundi" << "Cambodia" << "Cameroon" << "Canada" << "Cape Verde" << "Cayman Islands"
                          << "Central African Republic" << "Chad" << "Chile" << "China" << "Christmas Island" << "Cocos (Keeling) Islands" << "Colombia" << "Comoros" << "Congo"
                          << "Congo, the Democratic Republic of the" << "Cook Islands" << "Costa Rica" << "Côte d'Ivoire" << "Croatia" << "Cuba" << "Curaçao" << "Cyprus"
                          << "Czech Republic" << "Denmark" << "Djibouti" << "Dominica" << "Dominican Republic" << "Ecuador" << "Egypt" << "El Salvador" << "Equatorial Guinea"
                          << "Eritrea" << "Estonia" << "Ethiopia" << "Falkland Islands (Malvinas)" << "Faroe Islands" << "Fiji" << "Finland" << "France" << "French Guiana"
                          << "French Polynesia" << "French Southern Territories" << "Gabon" << "Gambia" << "Georgia" << "Germany" << "Ghana" << "Gibraltar" << "Greece"
                          << "Greenland" << "Grenada" << "Guadeloupe" << "Guam" << "Guatemala" << "Guernsey" << "Guinea" << "Guinea-Bissau" << "Guyana" << "Haiti"
                          << "Heard Island and McDonald Islands" << "Holy See (Vatican City State)" << "Honduras" << "Hong Kong" << "Hungary" << "Iceland" << "India"
                          << "Indonesia" << "Iran, Islamic Republic of" << "Iraq" << "Ireland" << "Isle of Man" << "Israel" << "Italy" << "Jamaica" << "Japan" << "Jersey"
                          << "Jordan" << "Kazakhstan" << "Kenya" << "Kiribati" << "Korea, Democratic People's Republic of" << "Korea, Republic of" << "Kuwait" << "Kyrgyzstan"
                          << "Lao People's Democratic Republic" << "Latvia" << "Lebanon" << "Lesotho" << "Liberia" << "Libya" << "Liechtenstein" << "Lithuania" << "Luxembourg"
                          << "Macao" << "Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of" << "Madagascar" << "Malawi" << "Malaysia" << "Maldives" << "Mali" << "Malta"
                          << "Marshall Islands" << "Martinique" << "Mauritania" << "Mauritius" << "Mayotte" << "Mexico" << "Micronesia, Federated States of"
                          << "Moldova, Republic of" << "Monaco" << "Mongolia" << "Montenegro" << "Montserrat" << "Morocco" << "Mozambique" << "Myanmar" << "Namibia" << "Nauru"
                          << "Nepal" << "Netherlands" << "New Caledonia" << "New Zealand" << "Nicaragua" << "Niger" << "Nigeria" << "Niue" << "Norfolk Island"
                          << "Northern Mariana Islands" << "Norway" << "Oman" << "Pakistan" << "Palau" << "Palestinian Territory, Occupied" << "Panama" << "Papua New Guinea"
                          << "Paraguay" << "Peru" << "Philippines" << "Pitcairn" << "Poland" << "Portugal" << "Puerto Rico" << "Qatar" << "Réunion" << "Romania"
                          << "Russian Federation" << "Rwanda" << "Saint Barthélemy" << "Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha" << "Saint Kitts and Nevis" << "Saint Lucia"
                          << "Saint Martin (French part)" << "Saint Pierre and Miquelon" << "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines" << "Samoa" << "San Marino" << "Sao Tome and Principe"
                          << "Saudi Arabia" << "Scotland" << "Senegal" << "Serbia" << "Seychelles" << "Sierra Leone" << "Singapore" << "Sint Maarten (Dutch part)" << "Slovakia" << "Slovenia"
                          << "Solomon Islands" << "Somalia" << "South Africa" << "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" << "South Sudan" << "Spain" << "Sri Lanka" << "Sudan"
                          << "Suriname" << "Svalbard and Jan Mayen" << "Swaziland" << "Sweden" << "Switzerland" << "Syrian Arab Republic" << "Taiwan, Province of China"
                          << "Tajikistan" << "Tanzania, United Republic of" << "Thailand" << "Timor-Leste" << "Togo" << "Tokelau" << "Tonga" << "Trinidad and Tobago" << "Tunisia"
                          << "Turkey" << "Turkmenistan" << "Turks and Caicos Islands" << "Tuvalu" << "Uganda" << "Ukraine" << "United Arab Emirates" << "United Kingdom"
                          << "United States" << "United States Minor Outlying Islands" << "Uruguay" << "Uzbekistan" << "Vanuatu" << "Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of" << "Viet Nam"
                          << "Virgin Islands, British" << "Virgin Islands, U.S." << "Wallis and Futuna" << "Western Sahara" << "Yemen" << "Zambia" << "Zimbabwe";
        }
        /// TODO: Get the country list in english
        else return;

        COUNTRY_CODE << "AF" << "AX" << "AL" << "DZ" << "AS" << "AD" << "AO" << "AI" << "AQ" << "AG" << "AR" << "AM" << "AW" << "AU" << "AT" << "AZ"
                     << "BS" << "BH" << "BD" << "BB" << "BY" << "BE" << "BZ" << "BJ" << "BM" << "BT" << "BO" << "BQ" << "BA" << "BW" << "BV" << "BR"
                     << "IO" << "BN" << "BG" << "BF" << "BI" << "KH" << "CM" << "CA" << "CV" << "KY" << "CF" << "TD" << "CL" << "CN" << "CX" << "CC"
                     << "CO" << "KM" << "CG" << "CD" << "CK" << "CR" << "CI" << "HR" << "CU" << "CW" << "CY" << "CZ" << "DK" << "DJ" << "DM" << "DO"
                     << "EC" << "EG" << "SV" << "GQ" << "ER" << "EE" << "ET" << "FK" << "FO" << "FJ" << "FI" << "FR" << "GF" << "PF" << "TF" << "GA"
                     << "GM" << "GE" << "DE" << "GH" << "GI" << "GR" << "GL" << "GD" << "GP" << "GU" << "GT" << "GG" << "GN" << "GW" << "GY" << "HT"
                     << "HM" << "VA" << "HN" << "HK" << "HU" << "IS" << "IN" << "ID" << "IR" << "IQ" << "IE" << "IM" << "IL" << "IT" << "JM" << "JP"
                     << "JE" << "JO" << "KZ" << "KE" << "KI" << "KP" << "KR" << "KW" << "KG" << "LA" << "LV" << "LB" << "LS" << "LR" << "LY" << "LI"
                     << "LT" << "LU" << "MO" << "MK" << "MG" << "MW" << "MY" << "MV" << "ML" << "MT" << "MH" << "MQ" << "MR" << "MU" << "YT" << "MX"
                     << "FM" << "MD" << "MC" << "MN" << "ME" << "MS" << "MA" << "MZ" << "MM" << "NA" << "NR" << "NP" << "NL" << "NC" << "NZ" << "NI"
                     << "NE" << "NG" << "NU" << "NF" << "MP" << "NO" << "OM" << "PK" << "PW" << "PS" << "PA" << "PG" << "PY" << "PE" << "PH" << "PN"
                     << "PL" << "PT" << "PR" << "QA" << "RE" << "RO" << "RU" << "RW" << "BL" << "SH" << "KN" << "LC" << "MF" << "PM" << "VC" << "WS"
                     << "SM" << "ST" << "SA" << "SQ" << "SN" << "RS" << "SC" << "SL" << "SG" << "SX" << "SK" << "SI" << "SB" << "SO" << "ZA" << "GS"
                     << "SS" << "ES" << "LK" << "SD" << "SR" << "SJ" << "SZ" << "SE" << "CH" << "SY" << "TW" << "TJ" << "TZ" << "TH" << "TL" << "TG"
                     << "TK" << "TO" << "TT" << "TN" << "TR" << "TM" << "TC" << "TV" << "UG" << "UA" << "AE" << "GB" << "US" << "UM" << "UY" << "UZ"
                     << "VU" << "VE" << "VN" << "VG" << "VI" << "WF" << "EH" << "YE" << "ZM" << "ZW";

    }

    QString getCodeForCountry(const QString &country){
        int index = COUNTRY_LIST.indexOf(country);
        if (index == -1) return "";
        else return COUNTRY_CODE.at(index);
    }

    QString getCountrFromCode (const QString &code){
        int index = COUNTRY_CODE.indexOf(code);
        if (index == -1)  return "";
        else return COUNTRY_LIST.at(index);
    }

    qint32 getIndexFromCode(const QString &countryCode){
        return COUNTRY_CODE.indexOf(countryCode);
    }

    QString getCodeFromIndex (int index){
        if (index == -1)  return "";
        else return COUNTRY_CODE.at(index);
    }

    QStringList getCountryList() const {return COUNTRY_LIST;}
    QStringList getCodeList() const {return COUNTRY_CODE;}

private:
    QStringList COUNTRY_LIST;
    QStringList COUNTRY_CODE;


};

#endif // COUNTRIES_H
```

My loader.h

```
#ifndef LOADER_H
#define LOADER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QQuickWindow>

#include "countries.h"


class Loader : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Loader(QObject *parent = nullptr, CountryStruct *cs = nullptr);
    ~Loader();
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList getCountryList() {return countries->getCountryList();}
    Q_INVOKABLE QStringList getCountryCodeList() {return countries->getCodeList();}
signals:

public slots:

private:
    // The list of countries and their codes.
    CountryStruct *countries;
};

#endif // LOADER_H
```

My loader.cpp

```
#include "loader.h"

Loader::Loader(QObject *parent, CountryStruct *cs) : QObject(parent)
{
    countries = cs;
    countries->fillCountryList();
}

Loader::~Loader(){

}
```

And finally my main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "loader.h"

CountryStruct countries;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    Loader loader(nullptr,&countries);
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("loader", &loader);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

This was compiled with MSVC2015 32bits (as is required by the actual project where this is from) using Qt 5.9

The problem is illustrated in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: How do you want this output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set [property z](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#z-prop) to a high value with respect to the other items, for example `1` since the default z is `0`.

```
VMAutoCompleteComboBox{
    id: diagDBDefaultCountry
    z: 1 // <--
    // ...
```

[image]

Comment: HAHAHAAH I tried setting it on each of the entries and on the list view but not on the actual combo box!! Thank you so much!!